# print str and int without "( ' ," in Python with JSON

Tags: python, json, string, printing, int

I am currently working with JSON and Python and I have a problem.
When I write:

```
x = {}
x['red'] = {'name': "red"}

y = {}
y['red'] = {'p': 1}


z = x['red']['name'], y['red']['p']

print(z)
```

I get back:

```
('red', 1)
```

But I want it like:

```
red1
```

Without using

```
print(x['red']['name'], y['red']['p'])
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we resolve the variables in the line

```
z = x['red']['name'], y['red']['p']
```

we get this:

```
z = "red", 1
```

This is, in Python the same as writing:

```
z = ("red", 1)
```

This line defines a data-type called a "tuple". It is similar to a list. When you use `print` to write out the value of this variable, Python formats this as such and adds the parens.

If you want the string `"red1"` as output, you need to do some minor string processing. In your tuple, your first item is a string, the next is an integer. Those two are not directly concatenable in Python using `+`. You either need to convert (cast) the number first, or use a string formatting function:

#### Example 1 - Using str() to cast the number to string

```
z = x['red']['name'] + str(y['red']['p'])
```

#### Example 2 - Using simple string formatting

```
z = '%s%s' % (x['red']['name'], y['red']['p'])
```

#### Example 3 - Using f-strings

```
z = f"{x['red']['name']}{y['red']['p']}"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that long comment. I tried the first one and got out. `('red', '1')` instead of `('red', 1)`. But the second one worked just like I wanted it to work. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Yes. I realised that in my first version I had a small typo. It has since been fixed.

Comment: I still get the same output in the first one, I think that's because str() doesn't work with JSON. (Or at least that's my guess)

Comment: I just retried my 3 examples, and they all work as expected. Maybe you need to reload the page?

Comment: ... also, just about terminology: In Python the `{...}` structures are called "dictionaries" or "dicts" for short. You can convert these to and from JSON using the `json` module. But for your code that conversion is not necessary.

Comment: No, the first one doesn't work for me. Same output as before. And I copy pasted it exactly like you wrote it.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make that clear in my original comment, but I cut my code down a bit so the question was easier to understand. In my whole code I need JSON

Comment: We might be talking about different example. I added headings to the answer numbering the different examples.

Comment: If you need JSON output, you can just pass your Python dictionary to [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

Comment: I completely rewrote my test code and now it works... I don't know why... I'm sorry :p

Comment: I actually work with json.dumps in my original code :)

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the string, easy:

```
z = y['red']['name'] + str(z['red']['p'])
print(z)
```

You need to call `str()` around `z['red']['p']` because it's an integer. By converting it to a string, you can then concatenate the two strings into one string

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick comment, but with "Without using: `print(y['red']['name'], z['red']['p'])`" I meant that I want to convert into the "z" before using print. Thant means: `print(z)` should return `red1`

Comment: @SkyThaKid Simply do `z = y['red']['name'] + z['red']['p']`, then `print(z)`

Comment: Or `print(*z, sep='')`

Comment: @TerryA That's what I did, but it seems like it doesn't work with JSON, sadly

Comment: Hey, I just rewrote my test code and now it works for some reason. I don't know what I did wrong, but I'm sorry :p. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

When you type `z = x['red']['name'], y['red']['p']` Python automatically takes it as tuple. 
But you want this to be treated as string and get concatenated results.

for this you may use,

```
z = str(x['red']['name']) + str(y['red']['p'])
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the comment, but that doesn't seem to work with Python and JSON. I still get the same output. But the comment from "exhuma" already solved it. :)

Answer (score -1):

`print(''.join(z))` does the trick.

Cheers

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/MinorRoyalTrace

Edit: use `print(''.join(str(element) for element in z))` instead for handle `str`+ `int`

Comment: This doesn't exactly work - remember that `y` is a dictionary here

Comment: is not a dict, is a Tuple

Comment: Sorry, I misspell, I wanna mean Z

Comment: Ok, but even with `z`, that still doesn't work - please check your code

Comment: That's because you've changed your `1` from an int to a string. In the question, it's an integer

Comment: Ah, true. Didn't notice it was an integer. Sorry.